# Using Html.EditorFor with a list with optional object

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model like

```
public class A {
   // Properties - some of them are required some optional
   // Optional
   public class ICollection<B> Items { get; set; }
}
public class B {
    public string A {get;set;} // Required
}
```

To use the `Html.EditoFor(o => o.Items[0])` I must add an empty object to `Items` and as such this object is sent to the server causing `ModelState.IsValid` to be false (if the user didn't choose to add any `B`s.

How is the proper way of handling this? What would be an option is to create an `[Optional]` attribute for collections that could inspect the list and check if it contains just one object and if that object is the default object, then skip it.

The `Items` property is filled on client side by calling the controller that renders the partial view (`Html.EditoFor(o => o.Items[0])`) and then some more js-fiddle to ensure all indexs are correct.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to write Custom Validation Attribute and decorate it to your Property. In that attribute you can write your own logic to validate collection and return true or false which will get passed to IsValid check.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question on Github [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5678#issuecomment-272390471) and got an answer thet pointed me in the right direction.

## Alternative solution

```
// PartialView _AddContact.cshtml
@model App.Features.Customer.CustomerContactModel

@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Contacts[0]";
}

@Html.EditorForModel()

// PartialView _AddContacts.cshtml
@model IList<App.Features.Customer.CustomerContactModel>

@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Contacts";
}

@Html.EditorForModel()

// Usage Edit.cshtml
@Html.Partial("_AddContact", new CustomerContactModel())

// Usage Create.cshtml
@Html.Partial("_AddContact")

// Controller action called from javascript do append partial views to DOM
public IActionResult AddContact([FromForm] IList<CustomerContactModel> contacts)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewData["inline"] = true; // Different template for inline edit
                return PartialView(contacts);
            }
            return new JsonResult(ModelState)
            {
                StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };
        }
```